How to get a amount from all "child" of a field account in power bi?
Explaining the problem:
I have a table with the accounts and the total value, this is the "fact" table



Account
Amount




CC1035
-19000


CC1284
123400


CC1909
200


CC1024
3500



I also have a table with "account", at first I had only account and parent (almost like a graph). I used a method to get the recursive parents and put in levels:



Parent
Account
Level1
Level2
Level3
Level4





CC_Shared
CC_Shared





CC_Shared
CC_Adm
CC_Shared
CC_Adm




CC_Adm
CC1035
CC_Shared
CC_Adm
CC1035



CC_Adm
CC1284
CC_Shared
CC_Adm
CC1284



CC_Adm
CC1909
CC_Shared
CC_Adm
CC1909




CC_Report
CC_Report





CC_Report
RCC
CC_Report
RCC




RCC
CC_CSC_Sold
CC_Report
RCC
CC_CSC_Sold



CC_CSC_Sold
CC1909
CC_Report
RCC
CC_CSC_Sold
CC1909


CC_CSC_Sold
CC1024
CC_Report
RCC
CC_CSC_Sold
CC1024




Obs: account could be in different levels and in differents branches (method path doesn't work), for example:

CC_Report -> RCC -> CC_CSC_Sold -> CC1909
CC_Shared -> CC_Adm -> CC1909
I want a slicer, for example, using "CC_Adm" and returning the total amount, in this case would be:
-19000 + 123400 + 200 = 104600
The problem: I would like a way to get any account and get all child below this account and create an Income statement unsing level (1,2,3,4) hierarchy to show all below.
Any ideias using concatenate or something else. Thank you all.
I tried using concatenate and a measure, but always fail using the slicer
